# Terraform: Unable to fetch connection strings when using 'data' resource for existing cluster

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, mongodb-atlas, azure-private-link

I'm new to terraform, and trying to setup mongoatlas privatelink for an existing cluster. The issue here is that, terraform is able to setup the privatelink, but when I try to fetch the privatelink string, then it gives the following error

```
data.mongodbatlas_cluster.cluster-atlas.connection_strings[0].aws_private_link is empty map of string
```

I'm using data resource of terraform to fetch the details of the cluster. Though I have read on some forums that data resource are read before creating resources so for that I'm using depends_on on the data resource but still facing the issue here.

My cluster code:

```
data "mongodbatlas_cluster" "cluster-atlas" {
project_id                   = var.atlasprojectid
name                         = "mongoatlas-cluster-xxxxxxx"
depends_on                   = [time_sleep.wait_300_seconds]
}
output "atlasclusterstring" {
     value = data.mongodbatlas_cluster.cluster-atlas.connection_strings

}
output "plstring" {
value = lookup(data.mongodbatlas_cluster.cluster- 
atlas.connection_strings[0].aws_private_link, aws_vpc_endpoint.ptfe_service.id)
}
```

Comment: What is the output of `atlasclusterstring`?

Comment: At the output itself it fails with the error message. But when I re-run plan I get all the values

Comment: [The documentation lists that attribute as deprecated](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/mongodb/mongodbatlas/latest/docs/resources/cluster#connection_strings.aws_private_link), and suggests using `connection_strings.private_endpoint[n].srv_connection_string` instead.